# How can I let the match function continue to run after a value is matched but the output is zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to do this without using Macro?

[image]

Basically, I want the formula that will convert the first table into the second table, where user key information on the highlighted yellow cells (E.g. 1 and A) and they get the output.

It involves Matching more than one column (since there may be multiple column with the same NAME)

Feel free to clarify with me if the explanation is unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever have one match for each letter and they are numbers you can use =SUMIF

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not necessarily numbers. Is there another way to do it for non-number?

Comment: Not without writing VBA or using an extender like Kutools from https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html